# rewriteurl is not working for files

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
    RewriteCond $1 [A-Z] 
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(?i:gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|cgi|ttf|otf|eot|woff|pdf|doc)$
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,R] 
    RewriteMap articlemap "txt:/etc/httpd/conf/map.txt"
    RewriteCond ${articlemap:$1} !=""
    RewriteRule "/(.*)" http://landingsite.com/$1 [P]
```

this is what I did. when a user hits mysite.com/article1 for example it does display http://landingsite.com/article1 but the stylesheet and javascript files are not found.
I would like to add that to my rules I am stuck here cant get it to work

for info stylesheet and js are located under /assets folder
so when I go to mysite.com/assets/app.js its blank 
if you go to http://landingsite.com/assets/app.js then you see the javascript

Answer (score 1):

Use these `RewriteCond`s before `RewriteRule` to check if it is requesting existing folders or existing files

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```